# GROUP BY statement with additive results in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query I'm using:

```
SELECT
   cm.id, name, role_type
FROM 
   main_creditmaster cm INNER JOIN main_person p on cm.person_id=p.id
WHERE
   tv_series_id=8 order by name
```

This gives me the following results:

```
id      name                role_type
5890    Daniel Dae Kim      0
20764   Evangeline Lilly    0
57271   Jorge Garcia        0
57271   Jorge Garcia        1
```

I want to group the person_id, but I also want to show all the `role_types` the user has. The final result I want to get is as follows, with 'Jorge Garcia's' roles combined into one entry:

```
id      name                role_type
5890    Daniel Dae Kim      0
20764   Evangeline Lilly    0
57271   Jorge Garcia        0,1
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `group by` and `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT cm.id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(role_type) as roles
FROM main_creditmaster cm INNER JOIN
     main_person p
     on cm.person_id = p.id
WHERE tv_series_id = 8
GROUP BY cm.id, name
order by name
```